Offsetting polybeziers
I am trying to achieve something equivalent to Inkscape's stroke-to-path, which takes a stroke of a given width and transforms it into a path that has the same visible outline, but in Python.
My current strategy would be:

transform the multispline to a polyline
offset it by given amount (using shapely)
break the offset at sharp corners
approximate the broken segments with splines (using beziers.py)
re-combine the approximations

This is because a simple offsetting strategy will produce ugly results (self-intersecting curves) at sharp corners (and won't let me control joins and caps like shapely does).
How does that sound? Is the beziers-to-poly-and-back a good strategy? until now it's giving me good results, but I'm wondering if there are any pitfalls.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This doesn't appear to be a graphic design question, so I'm voting to close it. Sorry about that. This question may be more suitable for Computer Graphics Stack Exchange.

Try it and see!

@BillyKerr - I did as it on Computer Graphics Stack Exchange, wwhere it remained unanswered for a whole day. I peeked here and saw that there was a "python" tag (absent in CGSE) and I thought I'd give it a try.

@ZachSaucier - I did try, and it actually looks too good to be true on the cases I came up with, so I was looking for someone to tell me if there are pitfalls.
But thanks to both
